# What style would you say this cassette tape packaging is?

Tags: style-identification, packaging, history

I've provided some concept styles to a client and wasn't sure how to describe this style. What time period/style does this image evoke most?

[image: cassette packaging design]

Comment: Late 60s through early 80s. It's no particular style other than perhaps "bold and geometric" with heavy use of plain sans-serif type.

Answer (score 4):

Well the invention of the cassette tape was in 1962 according to quick Google search.

So the time period would fit in the 60's & 70's. I would consider this style of packaging to be retro.

Some retro designs usually include:

- Line gradient patterns (see below example)

[image: line patterns]

- Dull flat colors / low saturation
- Bold patterns with high contrast